# How to get an older version of ros::rolling Docker image

Tags: docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Due to nav2 not being quite up-to-date, I can't use nav2 with official ros::rolling docker image. Here's the nav2 issue that has details on that:  https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/3364

While waiting for the nav2 issues to be fixed, is it possible to get an older version of the ros::rolling docker image?

My Dockerfile starts with this:

```
FROM ros:rolling  # Would like to roll this back one version
```

@tfoote

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411417/how-to-get-an-older-version-of-ros::rolling-docker-image/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2023-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First: even if you'd do this, I'm not sure how useful this would be.

Without a corresponding snapshot of the rest of the packages (and perhaps even `rosdistro/rosdep` DB), you cannot really install any additional packages without running the risk of introducing ABI incompatibilities. All newer packages would be fetched from the current Rolling repositories, which would not have any older versions available. And IIRC, the snapshot repository does not serve Rolling binaries (edit: see [this comment](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-packages-for-ros-2-rolling-ridley-2023-01-06/29094/3) by @nuclearsandwich on ROS Discourse fi).

Having written that: you can do this by specifying the "repo digest" of an image, instead of just a tag (which is what `ros:rolling` is), similar to how you'd "go back in history" in a Git repository.

As an example: `a06562802dbaf8db525a63218bd1a75f1ac4dd43f82c9c7891678c307b2a2ecf` is the hash of `osrf/ros:noetic-desktop` at around September last year. You can still fetch that image using:

```
docker pull osrf/ros@sha256:a06562802dbaf8db525a63218bd1a75f1ac4dd43f82c9c7891678c307b2a2ecf
```

Note: this is *not* the hash shown in the `IMAGE ID` column when you run `docker images`.

The tricky part would be finding the hash of that "older version of the ros::rolling docker image".

If you still have a machine around which has the older version -- or had, and ran a `docker pull ros:rolling` updating it -- you could use `docker inspect <IMAGE_ID>` to inspect it. Look for `RepoDigests` (or run `docker inspect <IMAGE_ID> | jq -r '.[].RepoDigests'`).

If you don't, you'd normally be out of luck I believe -- AFAIK, there is no API to get Dockerhub to list historical digests -- but apparently [docker-library/repo-info](https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info) keeps track of updates to Dockerhub (for official images). For `ros:rolling`, you'd have to check [ros/remote/rolling.md](https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info/blob/master/repos/ros/remote/rolling.md) (note: *not* a perma-link on purpose). To get historical hashes see [the commit history](https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info/commits/master/repos/ros/remote/rolling.md) of that file. [Here's the one for November 3, 2022](https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info/blob/5d98a01cb78207c6d17ac3947ac81f6d4f5ecdb4/repos/ros/remote/rolling.md) for instance. `docker pull ros@sha256:52e537f081689f869e17eba032a5823026460f47629f95bc67e21a5e56c2efc9` should get you `ros:rolling` as it was around that time.

> My Dockerfile starts with this:
>
> ```
> FROM ros:rolling  # Would like to roll this back one version
> ```

Use the same notation in `Dockerfile`s:

```
FROM ros@sha256:52e537f081689f869e17eba032a5823026460f47629f95bc67e21a5e56c2efc9
```

this would build an image based on `ros:rolling` from around the 3rd of November 2022.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2023-01-17**:
Confirmed you can cache these images yourself, but just like the snapshots discussion linked above, rolling is a moving target and there's no supported ways to get older versions. This is the point of rolling there's one version that we're all working on and we don't "support" older versions. That's the entire purpose of the distros to provide a stable target to develop against.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2023-01-24**:
Thanks for the advice. I'll do the common-sense thing and try to switch to Humble.